# Implement UItabbarController + UInavigationBar in project

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have navigation controller based project. In my project I have Splash Screen & Login Screen where i have hidden the navigation controller.

Now i have to implement TabbarController in the application and It need to be shown the screen after Login Page.

I want to add it in AppDelegate.But my problem is that I have set rootviewcontroller of Window as navigation controller.

And Now i want to use Tabbar controller also into the Appdelegate class.

I am finding difficulty into it.

Any help will be appreciated  a lot.

Comment: Download the example from this link and get benefitted... https://github.com/benbruscella/iPhone-TabBarController-With-NavigationController/downloads

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the rootviewcontroller as a tabbarcontroller and add a tab for your login screen but make sure to hide the tabbar initially, after the user login, you can remove the tab programatically and show the tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you really need that kind of navigation in your application, to me it sounds a bit of a unnecessary workaround and against guidelines. Try having a look at Apple's (["View Controller Programming Guide > Combined View Controller Interfaces"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1)) and maybe you'll find a more elegant solution to your problem.