# View switching and using Tab Bar Controller

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have App based on Tab Bar Controller, at the first Bar Item have item named 'Main'

On Main View Controller(according to 'Main' item on Tab Bar) i have `UIScrollView` for switching some Views via Page Control,
these Views contain UIButtons(for this context Button).

1) How can I go to Navigation Controller(Table View) is with TabBar Controller relatonship  from Button-Action,
   if i use:

```
TableViewController *newsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier@"NewsViewController"];
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:newsViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

have View without Root TabBar, but expect it.

2) How can I go to Navigation Controller(Table View) is not in TabBar Controller relationship from Button-Action,
   and in this case I need have Root `UITabBar` too on targer View

Comment: not getting.. do u want to switch tabs as per the action in Table View..?

Answer (score 0):

This sample application can help you a lot for it:

[Sample Application Link](https://github.com/benbruscella/iPhone-TabBarController-With-NavigationController/downloads)

and one more link for the same question is:

[Similar Question..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681319/implement-uitabbarcontroller-uinavigationbar-in-project)